Connecting to the deployed backend does not work
So I have my express backend code deployed on Render and I have the React front end on my local machine, if I try to run the frontend using the deployed url it does not work even tho when i try to do POST, PUT, GET in postman on the deployed link everithing works and when using the front end with the local server it works.
I cannot figure out what is wrong. If someone has any ideeas
Here is the server part ( for the database i am using sqlite )
const app = express();
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Connect to SQLite database
const db = new sqlite3.Database('mpp.db');

// Create users table if not exists
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    role TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'User'
)`);

// Create todos table if not exists
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todos (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
)`);

// Login endpoint
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
    db.get(sql, [req.body.email], (err, row) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ Error: "Error with email" });
        if (row) {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password.toString(), row.password, (err, response) => {
                if (err) return res.json({ Error: "Password hash error" });
                if (response) {
                    const id = row.id;
                    const name = row.name;
                    const role = row.role;
                    const token = jwt.sign({ id, name, role }, "jwt-secret-key", { expiresIn: '1d' });
                    res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true , secure: true});
                    return res.json({ message: "User login successfully", id, name, role });
                } else {
                    return res.json({ Error: "Wrong password" });
                }
            });
        } else {
            return res.json({ Error: "Email not found" });
        }
    });
});

// Middleware to verify user token
const verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, "jwt-secret-key", (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ Error: "Invalid token" });
            } else {
                req.userId = data.id;
                req.name = data.name;
                req.role = data.role;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        return res.json({ Error: "You are not authenticated!" });
    }
};

app.get('/', verifyUser, (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ Status: "Success", name: req.name, role: req.role });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:3001`);
});


Here is some of the front end part
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://mppbackend.onrender.com')
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.Status === "Success") {
                    setAuth(true);
                    setName(res.data.name);
                    setRole(res.data.role);
                } else {
                    setAuth(false);
                    setMessage(res.data.Error);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setAuth(false);
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);

I tried connecting the Front end to the deployed backend but it does not work, when i start the application it directs me to the login page and when i try to login using a email and a password that is in the database it just redirects me back to the login telling me that i am not authenticated
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('https://mppbackend.onrender.com/login', values)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.message == "User login successfully") {
                    navigate('/');
                } else {
                    alert(res.data.Error || res.data.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

